# json using with ajax to get data on another new page but page reload even using e.preventDefault(); function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

i want to get value on another new page and open new page without refresh
i am using here post method i am using json to get value 
i am new in this ajax code

i want to move from team.php controller page to team_detail.php without page refresh with value

i am using team.js file

```
$( ".all_athlete_list2" ).on( "click", function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
   var av = $(this).attr("data-json1");
   var av2 =   JSON.parse(av);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'team_details',
      data: {'teamId1=' : av2},
      complete: function(data){
       location.href = "team_detail;

      }
    });

});
```

my html part i am using anchor tag to get value

team.php file in which i am using anchor tag to move another page with value

```
   <?php foreach ($data['teams'] as $key => $value) { ?>
      <tr> <td>                               
        <a class="all_athlete_list2" style="color:black" data-json1='<?php 
         echo json_encode($value['team_id'], TRUE); ?>' data- 
         block="team_form_block" data-form="team_form" > <?php echo 
         $value['team_name']; ?>
       </a> 
    </td></tr>   
  <?php } ?>
```

my controller part in witch i want to use post method to get 'temId1' but not getting value of teamId1
this is Team_detail.php page on this page i want value using ajax without page refresh open this new page of Team_details of HTML page when click on anchor tag

```
public function index() {
 $userType = $this->session->userData('userType');
    $gymAccountId = '';
    if($userType == 1){
        $acountListResp = $this->Common->fetch_account('');            
        $data['data']['accounts'] = $acountListResp;
    }else{            
        $gymAccountId = $this->session->userData('gym_account_id');
    }
    $jk =  $this->input->get(); 
    $data1 = $jk['teamId1'];

    $athletesListResp = $this->Common->fetch_athletes($gymAccountId);
    $coachesListResp = $this->Common->fetch_coaches($gymAccountId);
    $teamListResp = $this->Team_details->fetch_team($data1);
    $fetch_coach_list = $this->Team_details->fetch_coach(); 

    $data['data']['athletes'] = $athletesListResp;
    $data['data']['coaches'] = $coachesListResp;
    $data['data']['teams'] = $teamListResp;
    $data['data']['coach_data'] = $fetch_coach_list;

   $this->load->template(array("Portal/Team_details" => ""), $data);
}
```

in model i am using simple select query to fetch data but in model not showing value of teamId1 in where condition its blank values showing

this is Team_details.php module page

```
public function fetch_team($data1){
             $all_id = $data1;
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT u1.first_name 'first_name(coach_name)',
       u2.first_name 'first_name(athlete_name)',
       dtt.team_id,
       dtt.team_name
FROM dev_team dtt 
INNER JOIN dev_teams_athlete  dtta on dtt.team_id = dtta.team_id
LEFT JOIN dev_user u1 on dtt.user_id = u1.user_id
LEFT JOIN dev_user u2 on dtta.user_id = u2.user_id  where dtt.team_id = '$all_id' ");

       $result = $query->result_array();
       return $result;
      }
```

> i want value without page refresh and redirect on another page with
>   value
>   i want to redirect my page with value at the 'Team_detail' on view page

Comment: I think this might be causing your page to refresh `location.href = "team_detail;
`.
What are you expecting to achieve with it?

Comment: sir, i want to move another page in controller as you see  index(); function is using and redirect at another page Portal/Team_details and i am not getting value

Comment: But is this supposed to be an asynchronous request? If so, meaning  you don't want the page to refresh, you should be making another AJAX request...

Comment: yes, sir your are correct i don't know much more about ajax please any example according to you move at another page with value, and its possible to move without page refresh move another page

Answer (score 2):

I see one synthax mistake in your team.js script: use

`data: {teamId1 : av2},`

instead of

`data: {'teamId1=' : av2},`

Comment: sir, have u any example to move another page without page refresh with value & sir i haven't this mistake

Comment: You have this mistake (not a fatal error). You have writen `data: {'teamId1=' : av2},` which means you post JSON object which has name 'teamId1=', and variable name 'teamId1=' is nowhere in your code. Sorry, I can analyse your problem more exhaustively just after my working hours.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help setting you in the right direction?

```js
$( ".all_athlete_list2" ).on( "click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var av = $(this).attr("data-json1");
  var av2 =   JSON.parse(av);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'team_details',
    data: {'teamId1=' : av2},
    complete: function(data){
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'team_detail',
        complete: function(data){
          // do something here with your response
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: sir, in get what i put from which i move to another page my value not coming on another page , my code is this any modify
<a class="all_athlete_list2" style="color:black" data-json1='<?php 
         echo json_encode($value['team_id'], TRUE); ?>' data- 
         block="team_form_block" data-form="team_form" > <?php echo 
         $value['team_name']; ?>
       </a>